# AWS Cognito custom provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

It seems I can't get a straight answer from the AWS docs or internet regarding support for custom IdP in AWS Cognito.

I am building a Shopify app which needs to authenticate user against Shopify (OAuth2 flow) which seems pretty generic IdP, except the OAuth2 url is different per Shopify client. There is a pattern that could be solved by wildcard definition:

```
store1.myshopify.com/admin/oauth
store2.myshopify.com/admin/oauth
another-store.myshopify.com/admin/oauth
```

All records match `*.myshopify.com/admin/oauth` pattern.

Is there any way how to make this working in AWS Congito?

Comment: You want to use AWS Cognito as primary IdP which should redirect users to Shopify IdP for the identity federation. Right?

Comment: Yes, AWS Cognito should be primary IdP with email login for users outside Shopify, in another words I need to have auth.MyApp.com and this should be running on AWS Cognito

Comment: You can [refer this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html) to add an OIDC identity provider(Shopify in your case) to a user pool. Or [refer this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFT-3TGLhZw&list=PLLFnfBgEq5NLV4pdmtKeTMe7H4Ejq_5IO&index=12), just replace Keycloak with Shopify.

Comment: I can't find an information that solves the dynamic URL range described in my post

Comment: Is it `1 cognito: 1 shopify` mapping or `1 cognito: n shopify` websites?

Comment: unfortunatelly 1 congito vs n shopify and that is the pain point. 1:1 works great

Comment: @Luke1988 OAuth2 is for Authorization - not for Authentication. Could you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve? You are going to build an app for Shopify users so that any Shopify store can use your app and then you are looking for a way to authenticate them?

Comment: @SampathDilhan yes, Shopify offers you the option to add "Log in with Shopify" which basically works just like Google / Facebook login. You type your store and using Shopify OAuth (Open ID?) you get the users identity